# Give an example of a set A with equivalence relations R and S for which S∘R ≠ R∘S

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations, function-and-relation-composition

I have to give an mere example where SR is not equal to RS.

I have tried a couple of numerical examples but am not able to figure any out.

Comment: What does $S \circ R$ mean?

Comment: Let A,B and C be three sets. Suppose that R is a relation from A to B, and S is a relation from B to C.
The composition of R and S, denoted by S∘R, is a binary relation from A to C, if and only if there is a b∈B such that aRb and bSc.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I've never come across relation composition before!

Anyway, this should work. Let $A = \{a, b, c\}$. Let $R$ equate $a, b$ and leave $c$ alone. Let $S$ equate $b, c$ and leave $a$ alone.

Then $aRSc$ but we don't have $aSRc$.

Let me know if I misunderstood the definition and I'll edit or delete my post.

Comment: We are given that R and S are equivalence relations on A

Comment: Yes $R$ is the equivalence reln such that $aRb$ and $bRa$, and only $cRC$. In other words we have two equivalence classes: $\{c\}$ and $\{a, b\}$. It's similar for $S$.

Comment: This is helpful, but could you give a numerical example for further understanding.

Comment: @HarrySolomon for a numerical example, replace $a,b,c$ with $1,2,3$, respectively.